# Making a variadic templete from another variadic template

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

To be honest I don't know how to start to search the solution for the problem I try to solve. Probably a solution already is. So the task is here.

I have a class that actually is template with 2 arguments:

```cpp
template <typename F, typename S>
class trans {...};
```

also I have another class that holds a chain of these "trans" classes like a tuple (example):

```cpp
class holder {
    using chain_type = std::tuple<trans<std::string, int>, 
                                  trans<int, float>, 
                                  trans<float, std::string>, 
                                  trans<std::string, json>>;
};
```

And as can be seen every second argument of a "trans" is the same as the next first. The chain:

```
std::string -> int -> float -> std::string -> json.
```

what would I want...I'd like to have some method to make this chain like this:

```cpp
template <typename ...Args>
class holder {
    using chain_type = trans_chain_create_t<Args...>;
};

holder<std::string, int, float, std::string, json> h;
```

Is it possible? 
I'm not very familiar with variadic templates and use them very rare.

Comment: Addendum, Adding `static_assert( sizeof...( Args ) >= 2, "There must be at least two types to create a chain." );` to `holder` class would be better to warn the users about its variadic template parameters' requirements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
template< typename F, typename S >
class trans {};

template< typename F, typename S, typename... Tail >
struct create_trans_chain;

template< typename F, typename S, typename... Tail >
using create_trans_chain_t = typename create_trans_chain< F, S, Tail... >::type;

template< typename F, typename S >
struct create_trans_chain< F, S >
{
    using type = std::tuple< trans< F, S > >;
};

template< typename F, typename S, typename Next, typename... Tail >
struct create_trans_chain< F, S, Next, Tail... >
{
    using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
        std::declval< create_trans_chain_t< F, S > >(),
        std::declval< create_trans_chain_t< S, Next, Tail... > >()));
};
```

Comment: Wow. That's simple I did not expect :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

With [Boost.Mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html), this is pretty short (as always):

```
template <typename ...Args>
using trans_chain_create_t =
    mp_transform<trans,
        mp_pop_back<std::tuple<Args...>>,
        mp_pop_front<std::tuple<Args...>>>;
```

`mp_transform` is basically a `zip`, we're zipping (`Args` without the tail) with (`Args` without the head) and then pairwise applying `trans` to that.

---

You can split the above by adding a helper metafunction, `zip_tail`:

```
template <template <typename...> class F, typename L>
using zip_tail = mp_transform<F, mp_pop_back<L>, mp_pop_front<L>>;

template <typename ...Args>
using trans_chain_create_t = zip_tail<trans, std::tuple<Args...>>;
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply unroll over a recursive template with an end specialization. How it works is described inside the code in comments. Take a look:

```
class json; // as you like that in your given code example... we need to define it
using input = std::tuple< std::string, int, float, std::string, json >;

// First we define a template struct which takes 1 parameter
// No need for a definition as we specialize later
template <typename INPUT >
struct Transform;

// for all inputs which have at minimum 3 template parameters 
// inside the std::tuple parameter we use this specialization 
template <typename FIRST, typename SECOND, typename NEXT, typename ... TAIL >
struct Transform< std::tuple<FIRST, SECOND, NEXT, TAIL...>>
{
    // As we have more than 2 parameters, we continue to transform
    // simply by using a recursive "call" to out Transform
    // struct
    using OUT = decltype( std::tuple_cat( 
        std::tuple< std::pair< FIRST, SECOND >>(),
        std::declval<typename Transform< std::tuple<SECOND, NEXT, TAIL...>>::OUT>()
        ));        
};

// This specialization is used for the last input as
// it has exactly 2 parameters  
template <typename FIRST, typename SECOND >
struct Transform< std::tuple<FIRST, SECOND >>
{
    using OUT = typename std::tuple<std::pair < FIRST, SECOND>>;
};

using OUT = Transform< input >::OUT;

template < typename T>
void Print()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Print< Transform< input >::OUT >();
}
```

There is no need to define your own `template <typename F, typename S>
class trans {...};` as we have `std::pair`;

Comment: Thank you for example with explanations. :)

Comment: Your code gives incorrect result as it produces nested tuples instead of a tuple of pairs. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/380cca399e295ee7

Answer (score 1):

Is too late to play?

If you want a non-recursive solution... `std::tuple_element` is your friend. (EDIT: well... apparently non-recursive: as pointed by Andrey Semashev, `std::tuple_element` itself is likely recursive).

Given a declared (observe: not defined; it's used only in a `decltype()`) helper function as follows

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto getChain (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
   -> std::tuple<trans<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>,
                       std::tuple_element_t<Is+1u, T>>...>;
```

your `trans_chain_create_t` simply (without recursion) become

```
template <typename ... Args>
struct trans_chain_create
 { using type = decltype(getChain<std::tuple<Args...>>
                   (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)-1u>{})); };

template <typename ... Args>
using trans_chain_create_t = typename trans_chain_create<Args...>::type;
```

The following is a full compiling (C++14 is enough) example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename, typename>
class trans
 { };

class json
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto getChain (std::index_sequence<Is...>)
   -> std::tuple<trans<std::tuple_element_t<Is, T>,
                       std::tuple_element_t<Is+1u, T>>...>;

template <typename ... Args>
struct trans_chain_create
 { using type = decltype(getChain<std::tuple<Args...>>
                   (std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)-1u>{})); };

template <typename ... Args>
using trans_chain_create_t = typename trans_chain_create<Args...>::type;

template <typename ... Args>
struct holder
 { using chain_type = trans_chain_create_t<Args...>; };

holder<std::string, int, float, std::string, json> h;
int main ()
 {
   using H = holder<std::string, int, float, std::string, json>;
   using CT1 = typename H::chain_type;
   using CT2 = std::tuple<trans<std::string, int>, 
                          trans<int, float>, 
                          trans<float, std::string>, 
                          trans<std::string, json>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<CT1, CT2>, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Thing is, `tuple_element` itself is likely recursive.

Comment: @AndreySemashev - Uhmmm... I suspect you're right... you've convinced me: added another answer that transform your solution in a non recursive one. Hoping `std::tuple_cat()` isn't recursive.

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from the Andrey Semashev's answer... a non recursive (and no `std::tuple_element`) version.

Given some declared function (not needs of definition: are used only inside `decltype()`)

```
template <std::size_t N, std::size_t I, typename, typename>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<(I == N), std::tuple<>> filter ();

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t I, typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<(I < N), std::tuple<trans<T1, T2>>> filter ();

template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2,
          std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto getChain (std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>,
                         std::index_sequence<Is...>)
   -> decltype(std::tuple_cat(filter<N, Is, Ts1, Ts2>()...));
```

you can write `trans_chain_create`(`_t`) as follows

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct trans_chain_create
 {
   using Tpl1 = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
   using Tpl2 = std::tuple<Ts..., T>;
   using IndS = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)+1u>;

   using type = decltype(getChain<sizeof...(Ts)>
                   (std::declval<Tpl1>(), std::declval<Tpl2>(), IndS{}));
 };

template <typename ... Args>
using trans_chain_create_t = typename trans_chain_create<Args...>::type;
```

The following is a full compiling (C++14 is enough) example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

template <typename, typename>
class trans
 { };

class json
 { };

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t I, typename, typename>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<(I == N), std::tuple<>> filter ();

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t I, typename T1, typename T2>
constexpr std::enable_if_t<(I < N), std::tuple<trans<T1, T2>>> filter ();

template <std::size_t N, typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2,
          std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr auto getChain (std::tuple<Ts1...>, std::tuple<Ts2...>,
                         std::index_sequence<Is...>)
   -> decltype(std::tuple_cat(filter<N, Is, Ts1, Ts2>()...));

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct trans_chain_create
 {
   using Tpl1 = std::tuple<T, Ts...>;
   using Tpl2 = std::tuple<Ts..., T>;
   using IndS = std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)+1u>;

   using type = decltype(getChain<sizeof...(Ts)>
                   (std::declval<Tpl1>(), std::declval<Tpl2>(), IndS{}));
 };

template <typename ... Args>
using trans_chain_create_t = typename trans_chain_create<Args...>::type;

template <typename ... Args>
struct holder
 { using chain_type = trans_chain_create_t<Args...>; };

holder<std::string, int, float, std::string, json> h;

int main ()
 {
   using H = holder<std::string, int, float, std::string, json>;
   using CT1 = typename H::chain_type;
   using CT2 = std::tuple<trans<std::string, int>, 
                          trans<int, float>, 
                          trans<float, std::string>, 
                          trans<std::string, json>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<CT1, CT2>, "!" );
 }
```